# Combinatorics when can you freely pick and when can you not?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm struggling trying to understand a key concept in combinatorics, namely when can you freely pick the "first" when counting and when can you not?

As an example take this common question: How many ways are there to divide $2n$ people into pairs? One solution (that I understand) is just $\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}$. This solution I understand, enumerate all the possibilities then account for all double counting.

An alternative solution for the same problem goes something like this: If you order all the people up, there are $2n-1$ ways to pick the partner for the first person, $2n-3$ ways to pick a partner for the next person etc. until you get as a result: $2n-1 * 2n-3 * 2n-5* ...*3 *1$

**This is part I do not understand.** **Why can we freely pick the "first person"?** Why do we not have to factor in that there are 2n choices for "the first" person?  I feel like in other combinatorics questions we cannot just freely pick "the first".

As an example of a problem where I feel you cannot do this: You draw 2 cards from a standard deck of 52, how many ways can you get a pair?

So you have 52 choices for the first card, once that's done, well there's only 3 cards left that match. Thus you you have $52 *3$ ways of doing this, and then you would divide by $2$ to account for the fact that $4\spadesuit$ $4\heartsuit$ is the same as $4\heartsuit$$4\spadesuit$ etc thus we have $52 *3 /2$

However, if I apply the same logic from above. Where I pick the first card "freely", and don't account for the 52 possible choices, then I would just say "well I picked the first card, there are only 3 matching cards thus my solution is $3/2$" which doesn't make a ton of sense.

I'm just trying to understand, when in counting problems can we sort of "freely" pick the first and when can we not?

Comment: It is a little bit difficult to answer this question in general, but let's take the pairing of $2n$ people. In your own words, the first step in the second method of counting is to "order all the people up". As such, there is no choice of $2n$ people for the first person. The first person is the first person. You have *already* chosen an order. That there are $(2n)!$ orders is irrelevant to the argument, which applies equally to any of those orders.

Comment: You should use parentheses when expressing the result for the number of ways of forming $n$ pairs of people from $2n$ available people.  The result should be $(2n - 1)(2n - 3)(2n - 5) \cdots (5)(3)(1)$.

Comment: @A.M. I appreciate you taking the time, I apologize for such a delayed response. My only follow up would be why can we not then do the same for the card example? Pick one card, now select which of the 3 leftovers go with it? But in that case obviously the answer seems incorrect

Comment: @A.M to be very ornerny, say you did want to account for the (2n)! orderings. Could you say that there are in fact (2n)! orders of who is the first and who is not;; however, this would overcount by (2n)! thus we would end up cancelling out anyways?

Comment: @Jackson well, you can. Pick one card and then select one of the $3$ out of the $51$ remaining valid combinations, for an answer of $3/51$. You can alternatively count the number of possible pairs, $52\times 3$, and divide by the number of possible choices of two cards, $52\times 51$, for the same answer. You just have to make sure that you are dividing by the correct symmetry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the card problem that is puzzling you is:

$\boxed{\text{The # of ways counted depends upon the sample space chosen}}$

If I choose a sample space of $52\times51$,
number  of ways = $52\times 3 $

and if I choose a  sample space of $1\times 51$, (i.e. first card any will do)
number of ways $= 1\times 3$

Probability = (favorable outcomes)/(sample space), and the important point to note is that when favorable outcomes are counted in a manner consistent with the sample space chosen, the choices yield the same probability

Comment: I guess the question then is how do you know if the sample space you've chosen is valid for the purpose of counting. Why freely picking one works in one case and not another is not rigorously obvious to me. Intuitively I sort of see it, but I couldn't explain why

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. The numerator and denominator have to be logically consistent with one another. One other question though, does your method not involve dividing by 2 to cancel out duplicates?

Comment: You can use either permutations or combinations as long as the numerator and denominator are consistent.